# Is there any reason typing the letter n would lose focus on an input field?

Tags: javascript, material-ui, formik

Using Material UI with Formik

Everytime the user hits the letter 'n' - no other letter does this - the focus goes up to the parent

Comment: Could you provide some example code or a reproduction in JSFiddle or somewhere similar?

Comment: @j3py Please don't ask for Fiddles or any other code at 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Code should be included right in the question.

Comment: Agreed, it should be in an ideal world, but for some people it is easier to create a reproduction in something they are already familiar with.  So I stand-by my suggestion for new users.  The original question can be updated later to reflect what's in the third party site.

Comment: unsure why, but adding in event.stopPropagation() fixed it - for whatever reason hitting 'n' caused the parent to get the focus so just stopped it from being able to propagate on key down

Comment: @j3py Stack Overflow is a knowledge base. It's not just for one person to post a question and get an answer. When links to code are posted, it makes it more difficult for us to answer, which reduces the chance of the OP getting an answer. And, when answers are given, but then the link dies over time, others who find the question have no idea what it's asking about. There's no reason someone can't post their code here. It's no more difficult (in fact it's much simpler) than posting that code somewhere else.

Comment: @j3py *Particularly* for new users, at least IMO, we should reiterate the FAQ. Questions should be self-contained; a runnable example off-site is a bonus, the question itself should contain enough code so people can provide feedback without having to make clicky.

Comment: @DaveNewton Why an "off-site" runnable example when we can have a runnable example right in the question?

Comment: @ScottMarcus More full-featured runnable examples are a bonus; personally I find JSFiddle/etc. easier to deal with than the SO snippets. As I stated: self-contained questions are the preferable resource--but I have a better experience with dedicated JS sites when modifying/extending/etc. someone else's code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @DaveNewton and ScottMarcus.

Comment: @user2264404 you can answer your own question if your want!  It might be helpful for others.